# Select grouped by a COUNT subquery

Tags: mysql, join, count, subquery

I've been struggling with this task for a while and since I cannot solve it by my own + google + MySQL docs, I'm turning to you guys.

I want to retrieve the newest Client's IDs that are related to a specific Item, grouped by:

- Client's type (A, B, C - without D)
- general number of Items that Client is related to

If a given type of a client has the same number of related Items, I want to get the newest one (hence `MAX(Client.id)` below).

My (simplified) tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Client` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clientType` ENUM ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `Item` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `ClientHasItem` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `clientId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `itemId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_ClientHasItem_itemId_Item_id` (`itemId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ClientHasItem_clientId_client_id` FOREIGN KEY (`clientId`) REFERENCES `Client` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ClientHasItem_itemId_Item_id` FOREIGN KEY (`itemId`) REFERENCES `Item` (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Example data:

```
INSERT INTO `Client` (`id`, `clientType`)
VALUES
    (1,'A'),
    (2,'A'),
    (3,'B'),
    (4,'C'),
    (5,'C'),
    (6,'D');
INSERT INTO `ClientHasItem` (`id`, `clientId`, `itemId`)
VALUES
    (2,1,1),
    (3,2,1),
    (4,2,2);
    (5,3,1),
    (6,3,2),
    (7,4,1),
INSERT INTO `Item` (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1,'Pizza'),
    (2,'Hot-Dog');
```

Expected result (for Item.id=1):

```
1 (because: type A, count=1)
2 (because: type A, count=2)
3 (because: type B, count=2)
4 (because: type C, count=1)
```

The closest I've come to a solution is here:

```
SELECT MAX(Client.id) AS id
FROM `Client`
  INNER JOIN `ClientHasItem` ON `Client`.`id` = `ClientHasItem`.`clientId`
  INNER JOIN `Item` ON `ClientHasItem`.`itemId` = `Item`.`id`
WHERE (`Item`.`id` = 1) AND (`Client`.`clientType` IN ('A', 'B', 'C'))
GROUP BY `Client`.`clientType`;
```

Counting query would look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `ClientHasItem`.`itemId`) 
FROM `ClientHasItem` 
WHERE `ClientHasItem`.`clientId`= MAX(Client.id) // id selected in the previous query.
```

PS. I have only_full_group_by mode ON and it has to stay that way. My MySQL version: 5.7.10

Comment: Can you also post some sample data along with expected result?

Comment: I've updated the question